# JHipster: replace drop down with text field for ID

Tags: jhipster

I am running JHipster "6.7.1" for this app.

I have a one-to-many entity relationship:

1. An employee can have many cars.
2. Each car has only one employee.
3. Car owns the relationship: I go to the car page and decide which employee owns it.

```
relationship OneToMany {
  Employee{car} to Car{Employee(name)},
}
```

The page generates with a drop-down of employees:

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="myApp.car.employee" for="field_employee">employee</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="field_employee" name="employee" formControlName="employee">
      <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
      <option [ngValue]="employeeOption.id === editForm.get('employee')!.value?.id ? editForm.get('employee')!.value : employeeOption" *ngFor="let employeeOption of employees; trackBy: trackById">{{ employeeOption.name }}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

But there can be thousands of employees, so the default drop-down isn't good. A type-ahead component would be good, or even a look up pop-up dialog, but right now I want something much simpler: just enter the ID of the employee. The user can use the employee page to find the ID of the employee and type it in.

I tried replacing the select with a text box to take and display the ID only, but this ended up showing `[object Object]`

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="client" id="field_client" formControlName="client"
      value="editForm.get('client')!.value?.id"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried `[value]="editForm.get('client')!.value?.id"`?

Comment: When I do that, the payload for the child field becomes just the ID - when the server is expecting the full JSON serialisation of the object, so I get a 400 Bad Request. Is it a simple thing to modify the field to send the whole object? NG is not my strong here..

Comment: The form model does not need to be exactly the same object as the one expected in body of the HTTP request, your component can transform them before calling the angular service.